# ASP .NET - Run required field validator and calloutextender in code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I am using ASP .NET (C#) and have a page with a listview linked to a sqldatasource.

The listview has a **InsertItemTemplate** which contains many textboxes.  I want to make all the textboxes required via the **RequiredFieldValidator** (and the **ValidatorCallOutExtender**).

Is there a way to do this in the codebehind instead of the aspx page?

Ideally I would like the page to validate each control with the same method with only the error message changing.

Comment: Could you be a bit more explicit about the kind of solution you seek?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it your question is about dynamically adding controls (and not about codebehind validation).

I didn't know and ran a few tests. It is possible to simply add (Validator)controls to the Controls property of the Form element, but controlling the order is not so simple (no `Controls.Insert()`).

So my advice would be not to use a plain TextBox but a UserControl. You could probably use Search&Replace to fix up the ItemTemplate.

Comment: With (only) codebehind you loose the advantages of client-side validation. I stick with the UserControls.